# Blazor WebAssembly: HandleFinancialTableChange Method Breakpoint Not Hitting on Dropdown Selection in .net8

Tags: blazor

I have a Blazor WebAssembly application with a component containing two dropdowns (InputSelect). The issue I'm facing is that when I select an item from the "Management" dropdown, the HandleFinancialTableChange method, which is associated with the @oninput event, doesn't hit the breakpoint in Visual Studio.

```cs
            <EditForm Model="@emp">
                <div>
                    <InputText @bind-Value="@emp.EmpId"></InputText>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="financialKPIsTable">Management:</label>
                    <InputSelect class="form-select select" @bind-Value="managementGroupId" @oninput="HandleFinancialTableChange">
                        @foreach (var gp in managementGroupDict)
                        {
                            <option value="@gp.Key">@gp.Value</option>
                        }
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
            
                <div>
                    <label for="dailyReviewTable">Corporation:</label>
                    <InputSelect class="form-select select" @bind-Value="corporation" @oninput="HandleDailyReviewTableChange">
                        @foreach (var corp in corporationDict)
                        {
                            <option value="@corp.Key">@corp.Value</option>
                        }
                    </InputSelect>
                </div>
            
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </EditForm>
@code{
    private void HandleFinancialTableChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        managementGroupId = e.Value.ToString();
        corporationDict = managementGroupDict.Take(3).ToDictionary(kv => kv.Key, kv => kv.Value);
        SubMethod();
    }
             }
```

My visual studio version
Visual studio 2022 -> 17.9.2

I've been working in debug mode, but the breakpoints in my HandleFinancialTableChange method are not being hit only when I select dropdown items. Strangely, all other methods are working as expected."

I've tried the following to address the issue:

Comment: You need to be clear.  This statement "only when I select dropdown items" says the break point is being hit when you change the value in the dropdown.  When else are you expecting the breakpoint to be hit?

Comment: When I modify the value in the dropdown, the associated @oninput event method executes the intended logic; however, breakpoints within the method do not get hit, despite the functionality being performed.